# mcelog: CPU is unsupported - how to fix it?

Tags: hardware, cpu

Got problem after trying to install samba4. Some of the packages throwing up error:

```
# apt-get install attr -y

// NO MATTER AT ALL PART:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
attr is already the newest version.     // OK, SO I GOT IT ALREADY

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer
required:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-63 linux-headers-3.13.0-63-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.   // OK I WILL DO
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
[master e97dd96] saving uncommitted changes in /etc prior to apt run
 Author: SOME_SECRET_USER 
 1 file changed, 11 insertions(+), 11 deletions(-)

// IMPORTANT PART:

Setting up mcelog (100-1fakesync1) ...
Starting Machine Check Exceptions decoder: CPU is unsupported
invoke-rc.d: initscript mcelog, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mcelog (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mcelog
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)



# cat /var/log/mcelog
cat: /var/log/mcelog: No such file or directory
```

What does it mean, how to fix or get around this problem? 
For now i'm assuming i got hardware CPU error.

My CPU on that host is:
AMD X2 3800+ (2Ghz).
OS: Ubuntu 14.04, x64, kernel 4.0
Tested on memtest - no error result.

Answer (score 0):

mcelog daemon isn't needed with AMD CPU, see:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1069652

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.